# FetchMode.JOIN to eagerly fetch a member list apparently yields cartesian product

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I'm trying to optimize a complex operation involving all the `Books` and `Videos` in multiple `Libraries` (this is not the actual domain, for nondisclosure reasons).

The code originally used `Criteria` to load all the `Libraries`, then loaded the member `Books` lazily by iterating.  I basically added a couple of `FetchMode` clauses:

```
  List<Library> library = session
            .createCriteria(Library.class)
             .setFetchMode("books", FetchMode.JOIN)
             .setFetchMode("videoShelves.videos", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .list();
```

The second `FetchMode` clause appears to work, or at least doesn't result in obvious problems.

The first, though, blows out the number of `Libraries` from 6 to 248. So it looks to me as if maybe each `Library` is replicated once for each  `Book` it has.

What are the conditions under which Hibernate might create unexpected duplicate instances when a `FetchMode` is added to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this behaviour is an `outer join`, as @TimBiegeleisen suggested.
For more information refer

[Hibernate does not return distinct results for a query with outer join fetching enabled for a collection (even if I use the distinct keyword)?](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword)

Possible solutions from the link provided above

1. Using `Set`

   `List<Library> library = ...; 
   return new ArrayList<Library>(new LinkedHashSet<Library>(library));`
2. Using the `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` result transformer

   `List<Library> library = session
               .createCriteria(Library.class)
                .setFetchMode("books", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("videoShelves.videos", FetchMode.JOIN).
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .list();`

But, the best solution is not fetching all data in one request of course. For an example, if you want to show a list of libraries (with number of books, for an example) you can use projections to load only data you want to.

Comment: Thanks, `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` of course did the trick. This is a legacy app that needs optimizing. It's lazily loading the books for each library, which takes a long time. `@BatchSize` on the books collection helps a lot, but it can negatively impact to other use cases that only access a few books per library. Though this approach creates a hidden dependency between the optimized query and the downstream usage patterns, the app has more serious design issues. Projections would mean heavier refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setFetchMode()` will, by default, result in an outer join, which is what you are currently observing.  If you want an `INNER JOIN` between the three tables then try this instead:

```
List<Library> library = session.createCriteria(Library.class, "library")
                               .createAlias("library.book", "books")
                               .createAlias("books.video", "videos").
                               .list();
```

Comment: Aliases don't fetch associated collections, as you know :)